# How can I stop Cardano Node correctly without running it as a service?

Tags: cardano-node, stake-pool, node, syncing

Is there a way to correctly stop `cardano-node` different than making it run as a service?

I have noticed that, since version 1.34.1, I'm getting the message `Validating chunk no. X out of Y.` every time I restart it.

I assume this is happening because I'm not stopping it correctly.

I'm using `tmux` and I just use `kill-session` command to stop my node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm using tmux and I just use kill-session command to stop my node.

That is probably not a safe shutdown.

For a safe shutdown you should go to the terminal where the `node` is running and send `Control-C`. You will then get a message like:

```
[mainnet:cardano.node.ChainDB:Info:5] [2022-05-30 05:32:03.82 UTC] Closed db with
 immutable tip at 1000a37390ad4590c317da8ec0b456b7d2a50b5a07ad6162cd3fb0b5f5862a7a
 at slot 62277555 and
 tip b1b90587bf4e55e88a0f59ebfd0e4010aabfcd4c5209921a77bb12f479f32df0 
 at slot 62322410

Shutting down..
```

This indicts a correct and safe shutdown.

Answer (score 4):

I think you should resume the session and press Control-C to stop cardano-node when you are running it in tmux.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen people suggest `kill -2 <PID>` as it sends a SIGINT (similar to CTRL-C), but it never quite completes for me. There is always 1 external network connection active and the main node process is still running, which I then `kill <PID>` after 10-15 minutes.

Although doing it this way does start up more quickly and avoids most of the `Validating chunk X of Y` work.